# Sonarqube custom rule giving back not failed test

Tags: java, sonarqube

So, i am trying to write a custom rule for sonarqube that it rise an isuess if it detect an REGEX that i pass them,

```
public class AvoidHardCodedUsers extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {
private static final String PATTERN = "ESOP\\d{7}";

@Override
public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
return Arrays.asList(Tree.Kind.STRING_LITERAL);
}

@Override
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
LiteralTree literalTree = (LiteralTree) tree;
String literalValue = literalTree.value();
if (literalValue.matches(PATTERN)) {
context.reportIssue(this, literalTree, String.format("Avoid using hard coded user in code @%s"));
}
}

}
```

On the test file of the plugin i put some error like the pattern, but the error messaje says there are not test failure,

I pass every type of String into the test class to match that pattern, but nothing taking the pattern as error.